# Are the dropDuplicates and select operation pushed after join, in case nothing is selected?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Given

```
     val a = List(1,2,3).toDF("a")
     val b = List(1,2,3).toDF("b")
```

Scenario 1

```
      a.filter(col("a").isNull).dropDuplicates().crossJoin(b).show()
      // display empty data frame as expected
```

Scenario 2

```
      val c = List().map(a => col(a))
      a.select(c:_*).crossJoin(b).show()
      // displays
      +---+
      |  b|
      +---+
      |  1|
      |  1|
      |  1|
      |  2|
      |  2|
      |  2|
      |  3|
      |  3|
      |  3|
      +---+
```

In scenario 2 as I am selecting no column from `a` and then doing cross join, I expected an empty data frame.

Scenario 3

```
       val c = List().map(a => col(a))
       a.select(c:_*).dropDuplicates().crossJoin(b).show()
       // displays
       +---+
       |  b|
       +---+
       |  1|
       |  2|
       |  3|
       +---+
```

Again I expected an empty data frame in Scenario 3. But in addition to the resultant data frame not being empty, `dropDuplicates` seems to happen after what the result in case of Scenario 2.

Am I missing something trivial. In what order are the `select, join and dropDuplicates` happening ? Is selecting nothing different from an empty data frame ?

Comment: Is it because you have 3 null elements when you do `a.select(c:_*)`, and since crossJoin is a cartesian join, it gives you this result ? 
`a.select(c:_*).count()` return 3